# Need help understanding causative and passive form: 外国人に質問を聞かれたが、答えられなかった。

Tags: grammar, conjugations, potential-form

I was reading up some lesson on causative and passive form online. I am still a little confused as to when and why use these form. For this example:

> plain form: 答える
>   passive form: 答えられる
>
> 外国人に質問を聞かれたが、答え**られ**なかった。
>   I was asked a question by a foreigner but I couldn't answer.

Why do we use passive here? What if I say:

> 外国人に質問を聞かれたが、答えなかった。

Does this mean the same? Or is this sentence even correct in the first place?

Comment: It's not passive form here, it is its potential form.

Comment: ah I see! I really got confused here.

聞かれた was the passive form and 答えられる like you said was potential form. Right?

Comment: Yes. Many verbs have the same potential and passive form.

Comment: Only the second group of verbs (aka Ichidan doushi) and 来る　have the same potential and passive forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「答{こた}えられる」 has ***three*** different usages and meanings.

> 1. **Honorific**: Used when describing someone higher up answering.

「その質問{しつもん}にはスミス様{さま}が答えられました。」

= "Mr. Smith (kindly) answered the question."

> 2. **Potential**: Used to express "can answer" or "to be able to answer".

「その質問は難{むずか}しすぎて答えられません。」

= "That question is too difficult (for me) to answer."

> 3. **Passive Voice**: Used to express "is/are/get(s) answerd" as opposed to the active voice form "to answer"

「Aの質問は私**に**、そしてBの質問はマサコさん**によって**答えられました。」

= "Question A was answered by me and Question B, by Masako."

＊You mentioned "***causative***", but the causative form is 「答え**させる**」and not 「答え**られる**」.

Finally, let us discuss the difference between 「答えられなかった」 and 「答えなかった」.

The former means that one was unable to answer a question (mostly or entirely because the question was too difficult).

The latter means that one chose not to (or declined to) answer a question even though one knew the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It's much clearer now.