# Explanation of 掛けられたら in this situation?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

I've come across this sentence 「暑い……こんな日に上着なんて掛けられたら怒鳴りつけちまうぜ」, which I think might roughly translate to "It's too hot to be wearing a coat on a day like this, though if (I) were to take it off, (I'd) be shouted at!"

Would 掛けられたら translate to if (I) would take off? I've only learnt it in the context 'To hang' as in a picture. I'm still around N5 but られたら conjugations are the most confusing to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/need-help-understanding-causative-and-passive-form/26173#26173

Comment: 上着を掛ける is like [this](https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&q=上着をかける).

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I didn't even think to check google images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「暑{あつ}い……こんな日{ひ}に上着{うわぎ}なんて掛{か}けられたら怒鳴{どな}りつけちまうぜ。」

「掛けられたら」 here is ***passive voice***, namely the famous "suffering passive".  A person does something to you and you are not happy about it.  You would not 怒鳴りつけちまう ("yell out loud") if you were not suffering, would you?

The three usages of 「れる・られる」 is explained [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/need-help-understanding-causative-and-passive-form/26173#26173).  Only the context will tell which one of the three meanings 「れる・られる」 is being used for.  Please remember that Japanese is an incredibly contextual language.  Had you asked just "What does 掛けられたら mean?", no one could have answered.  **Without any context, it could mean honorific, potential or passive voice**.

> "I would yell out loud if someone put a jacket on me on such a hot day like this."

I did no use the passive voice structure in my translation.  You could replace the "if someone put a jacket on me" part by "if I were made to wear a jacket".

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for explaining it and for the link.